Why can't I downcast generic wrapped in box in Rust
I have the following minimal code:
Rust Playground
use std::any::Any;

pub trait MyTrait: Any {

    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl MyTrait for Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        (**self).as_any()
    }
}

impl<T: MyTrait> MyTrait for Box<T> {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        (**self).as_any()
    }
}

struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

struct B<T: MyTrait> {
    data: T,
}

impl<T: MyTrait> MyTrait for B<T> {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn create_a() -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    Box::new(A {})
}

fn create_b_with_box() -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    Box::new(B {
        data: create_a(),
    })
}

fn main() {
    let my = create_b_with_box();


    let my1 = my.as_any().downcast_ref::<B<Box<dyn MyTrait>>>().unwrap(); // <-- this works

    // This fails even though I use the last stepped
    let my2 = my1.as_any().downcast_ref::<B<Box<A>>>().expect("Should work");
}

what I would like to do is downcast straight to the expected type but this fails:
let my2 = my.as_any().downcast_ref::<B<Box<A>>>().expect("Should work");

so I tried to downcast in steps and the first step worked but the second failed:
let my1 = my.as_any().downcast_ref::<B<Box<dyn MyTrait>>>().unwrap(); // <-- this works

let my2 = my1.as_any().downcast_ref::<B<Box<A>>>().expect("Should work"); // <-- This fails


You're attempting to downcast an &dyn Any to an &B<Box<A>> whereas the underlying concrete type is in fact an &B<Box<dyn MyTtrait>>.

but A implements MyTrait

@RazLuvaton that's irrelevant, it's not the same type you're not even using the MyTrait implementation of T in impl<T: MyTrait> MyTrait for B<T>

But my.as_any().downcast_ref::<B<Box<dyn MyTrait>>>().unwrap().data.as_any().downcast_ref::<A>().expect("Should work") works. Seems it cannot handle nested generics.
